# Aspherical manifold with superperfect fundamental group and non-trivial center?

Tags: gr.group-theory, smooth-manifolds, 3-manifolds

I am interested in knowing if there is a closed, (smooth) aspherical manifold $M$ (hyperbolic would be best) with superperfect fundamental group (that is to say, with $H_1(\pi_1(M);\mathbb{Z}) = H_2(\pi_1(M);\mathbb{Z}) = 0$; note $H_1(\pi_1(M);\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ is equivalent to perfect) and non-trivial center ($\mathbb{Z}_2$ would be best, but any f.g. Abelian group will do).

Also, assuming there is a manifold that fits the criteria, I would likely need a handlebody decomposition for the manifold, assuming the "standard handlebody procedure" for producing a closed, smooth manifold from a prescribed finite presentation of a/the fundamental group does not yield the smooth manifold in question (e.g., the "standard manifold" is not aspherical).

I found many hyperbolic 3-manifolds with superperfect fundamental group using SnapPy, but SnapPy evidently doesn't have a center "method" for the fundamental group method/class attached to 3-manifolds. Sage/GAP/MAGMA also appear not to be able to compute the center for an infinite finitely-presented fundamental group.

Thanks much in advance. I realize this is kind-of "shooting for the moon/stars".

Comment: In every dimension, the fundamental group of a hyperbolic manifold has trivial centre. There are no examples of what you want in dimension 2, but in dimension 3, there are  the Brieskorn homology spheres $\Sigma(p,q,r)$ for $1/p+1/q+1/r <1$. These are aspherical homology spheres which are Seifert fibred, so their fundamental groups have centre $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Glossary: $G$ superperfect means $H_1(G,\mathbf{Z})=H_2(G,\mathbf{Z})=0$.

Comment: The fundamental groups of aspherical manifolds are always torsion free for homological reasons, so a centre of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the best you can do.

Comment: @HJRW That's right, and the hyperbolic ones, at least (I think?), can't have a $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ or higher rank free Abelian group as a subgroup; I had looked up both those facts last night but forgot them. It's truly $\mathbb{Z}$ or nothing, thanks.

Comment: @HJRW Thanks so much for the Brieskorn homology spheres examples! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @HJRW Perhaps you mean that the center (if non-trivial) must contain $\mathbb{Z}$? Since the OP didn't specify the dimension one could take products of Seifert fibered spaces. This produces examples in dimension $3n$ with center $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: @DannyRuberman — of course. I said that $\mathbb{Z}$ is “the best you can do”, because the OP was hoping for $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses. If I may "go to the well" one more time, how may I specify a Brieskorn homology sphere in SnapPy?

Comment: One more point--there are well-known genus 2 Heegaard splittings (derived from well-known surgery diagrams) for the Brieskorn homology spheres with 3 exceptional fibers. See eg Boileau-Zieschang [link] (http://www.numdam.org/article/AST_1988__163-164__247_0.pdf)

Comment: I think SnapPy is all about hyperbolic manifolds. What are you hoping to learn/compute about those examples using SnapPy?

Comment: @DannyRuberman Just a finite presentation of the fundamental groups; I'll need that for the construction I'm doing

Comment: See section 2.3 of the Boileau-Zieschang paper; you'll need to compute the Seifert invariants first. You can find the answer in section 3.5.1 of Saveliev's book, Invariants for homology 3-spheres.  Did you only care about the 3-dimensional case? My comment above gives examples for dim = 0 mod 3, but probably there are ways to do dim = 1 or 2 mod 3.

Comment: @DannyRuberman Wow, that's awesome, thank you!

I'm actually going to take a fiber bundle with a torus as the base manifold and need the total space to be at least 6-dim'l at some point, so I could just use a 3-dim'l torus or a 2-dim'l torus and a higher-dim'l example of what you just suggested; it's kind-of "six of one, half a dozen of another" to me at this point.

However, modulo the dimension of the manifold, this is exactly what I needed, so thank you

Comment: @YCor Edited into OP

Comment: Someone should turn this discussion into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Per Lee's request, I've turned the discussion into an answer.

Suppose that $M$ is a closed connected oriented hyperbolic $n$ manifold, for $n$ at least two.  Then the fundamental group contains no torsion elements; also its center is trivial.  Both claims are exercises from the classification of isometries of hyperbolic $n$-space.

Thus there are no hyperbolic homology three-spheres with the property you desire.

However, there are many three-manifolds that are (integral) homology spheres (and so $\pi_1$ is super-perfect) and where $\pi_1$ has non-trivial abelian centre.  These are found among the [Seifert fibered spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_fiber_space).  The most famous of these is the [Poincare homology sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere#Poincar%C3%A9_homology_sphere), but this example is ruled out by your requirement that $M$ be aspherical.

More specifically, you should consider the "aspherical Brieskorn homology spheres" $\Sigma(p, q, r)$.  These are described at the Wikipedia page linked to immediately above, which also briefly sketches a presentation of their fundamental group.  If you want Snappy to compute things for you, then consult Figure 1 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1143644312) (say) for a surgery description of $\Sigma(p, q, r)$.  This paper also gives a short but useful discussion of the fundamental group.

Comment: I was and am planning on collecting the above in an answer, but was waiting for the book https://smile.amazon.com/Invariants-Homology-3-Spheres-Nikolai-Saveliev/dp/3540437967/ to come in at the library to make sure I have all I need for the presentation of the fundamental group and handlebody decomposition of the minimal Brieskorn homology sphere to meet my criteria; sorry if I dragged my feet posting this

Comment: I also need to know a product of generators representing a generator of the center; I can't edit the above

Comment: @JeffreyRolland - the presentation given by Boden, Herald, and Kirk (linked to in my answer) includes the generator $h$ of the center as one of the generators of the fundamental group.  They also clearly indicate $h$ in their Figure 1.

Comment: I got the book today, and it answered all my questions and more; I'll post an "answer" and my exciting MATLAB .m script to compute the Bézout coefficients corresponding to the relatively prime integers in the Brieskorn homology sphere tomorrow

Comment: Indeed, the book by Saveliev also explicitly includes the generator ℎ of the center as one of the generators of the fundamental group; thanks so much for the response